# Feign check body is not empty

Tags: java, spring, microservices, spring-cloud-feign

I use Feign in my micro service.
Sometimes my code gets (as response from remote client) 200 OK with body, but sometimes 204 without and I got here NPE. Is it possible to set body by default? or check whits is respose code and dont wait for body payload?
This is my code

```
@FeignClient(name = "ppppp", url = "${ppppp.url}")
public interface PClient {
    @PostMapping("/search")
    ResponseEntity<MyResult> searchAll(@RequestHeader("User") String user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend from `ResponseEntityDecoder`, customize your own feign client and implement your own `Decoder` where you can do whatever you want with the response.